# DOM appenchild at wrong position

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, appendchild

I have a problem with appendChild in a XML file. I wrote a little script to edit a XML file.
You can change the value of a node or add a new one.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
$element = $xpath->query('//parent/child[index="'.$index.'"]//'.$key)->item($i);

if($element){
    $element->nodeValue = $value[$i];
} else {
    $elementLast = $xpath->query('//parent/child[index="'.$index.'"]//'.$key)->item($i-1);
    $elementLast->appendChild($dom_object->createElement($key, $value[$i]));
}}
```

The new node is created but it looks like this

```
<child>Blablabla<child>new node</child></child>
```

So the new node is inserted in the last child node not after it like it should be.

Comment: `appendChild` appends a child, not a sibling.

Comment: oh man... what a dumb mistake. You're right. Thanks.